# Twig - Bootstrap 4 Layout with raw label

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I am using the `bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig` theme in symfony 3.4 and I would like to overwrite my label like this (add a download link to it):

```
{% use "bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig" %}
{% block post_file_widget %}
    {% set download_uri = form.file.vars.download_uri %}
    {{ form_label(form.file, 'label.file'|trans~'<a href="'~download_uri~'">('~'current.file'|trans~')</a>' }}

    {{- block('form_widget') -}}
{% endblock %}
```

This is the source text from the rendered form

```
<legend class="col-form-label">File &lt;a href="/uploads/5/c/5cb5daef7f214545309154.JPG"&gt;(current file)&lt;/a&gt;</legend>
```

This is the responsible shorted source code from the [bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig#L210):

```
<...>{{ translation_domain is same as(false) ? label : label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</...>
```

---

**What I have tried so far:**

1. Overwrite the `form_label` block with the `|raw` filter:

   ```
   {%- block form_label -%}
        {% set label = label|raw %}
        {{ parent() }}
   {%- endblock -%}
   ```
2. Or at my custom block adding the `|raw` filter:

   ```
   {{ form_label(form.file, 'label.file'|trans~'<a href="'~download_uri~'">('~'current.file'|trans~')</a>'|raw }}
   ```
3. If I copy the whole 30 lines from the `form_label` block of the `bootstrap_4_layout` and append at the responsible line the `|raw` filter **it's working**:

   ```
   <...>{{ translation_domain is same as(false) ? label|raw : label|trans({}, translation_domain)|raw }}</...>
   ```

But I think it's a very stupid and dirty solution to copy 30 lines of code only to append the `|raw` filter for it.

So my questions:

- Why does the first and the second approach not work?
- How do I display the download link as escaped html without copying the whole bootstrap `form_label` block as in the third approach?

Comment: With Symfony 5.1 it seems to work https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-form-improvements#allow-html-contents-in-form-labels (haven't tested it yet)